# Difference betwen 2 times is showing 12 in field of hours

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

```
$start_time = '10:36:23';  
$end_time = '10:36:26';   

$v =  strtotime($end_time) - strtotime($start_time);  


echo date("h:i:s", $v);
```

Result should be 00:00:03. But is showing 12:00:03.

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lowercase **h** gives you the hour in 12-hour format. So an hour of zero is after midnight which is 12 AM. If you use uppercase **H** it will display as you want.

```
echo date("H:i:s", $v);
```

Your difference is not actually a time, it is a time span.

Comment: This fixes the issue with the format, but be careful if `date.timezone` is not UTC - for instance, with a London timezone, this would result in `01:00:00` (as the UK were UTC+1 on 1 Jan 1970).

Comment: Thats is fixed. Tanks a lot to all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

The error in where you are echoing out ur date change it to this `echo date('H:i:s', $v);` with an uppercase H

Answer (score 0):

The difference calculation is correct, and `$v == 3`, but you are then using `date` to format it as a time.

This will output the local time equivalent of `1970-01-01 00:00:03 +0000`, which could vary based on local timezone (and possibly daylight savings time).

If you want to format a difference in such a way, you could use `gmdate` (which will show correctly regardless of local timezone) and a 24-hour clock:

```
echo gmdate("H:i:s", $v);
```

You could also use `DateTime`:

```
$start_time = new DateTime('10:36:23', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$end_time = new DateTime('10:36:26', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$diff = $end_time->diff($start_time);
echo $diff->format("%H:%I:%S");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a tip.

You can also use the datetime object to calculate the difference between two dates:

```
$start_time = new DateTime('10:36:23');  
$end_time = new DateTime('10:36:26'); 

$diff = $start_time->diff($end_time);

print_r($diff);
```

Result:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 3
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 0
)
```

Where the 's' stands for the number of seconds.